# Android JNI ReleaseByteArrayElements does not work

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i have got a problem at using Android JNI. I call a java method from native C. Everything works fine, BUT after a few seconds the APP crashes, because the maximum of 512 entrys of JNI refs is full (or the memory is full).

Here is my code:

```
int jniBluetoothSend( TJNIAdapter *pAdapter, byte *data, int dwLength )
{
JNIEnv *pEnv;
JavaVM *pVm = NULL;
jclass cls;
jmethodID methodId;
int nRet;
jbyteArray aData;

if ( pAdapter )
{
   pVm = pAdapter->pVm;
   ( *pVm )->AttachCurrentThread( pVm, &pEnv, NULL );

   if ( pAdapter->pClasses != NULL && pAdapter->pClasses->hgs_bluetooth != NULL )
   {
      // get function
      methodId = ( *pEnv )->GetMethodID( pEnv, pAdapter->pClasses->hgs_bluetooth, "write", "([BI)I" );
      if ( methodId )
      {
         aData = ( *pEnv )->NewByteArray( pEnv, dwLength);
         ( *pEnv )->SetByteArrayRegion( pEnv, aData, 0, dwLength, data);
         // write Data to device
         nRet = ( *pEnv )->CallIntMethod( pEnv, g_hgsBthObject, methodId, aData, dwLength );

         // and delete Reference -> so GC can cleanup
         ( *pEnv )->DeleteLocalRef( pEnv, aData );
      }
   }
   //( *pVm )->DetachCurrentThread( pVm ); -> // crashes as soon as getting called
}
return nRet;
```

}

Everytime "ReleaseByteArrayElements()" gets called a warning shows up in Android Log from dalvik:

```
JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x428e84a8) failed to find entry (valid=1)
```

So, i think, the problem is, that the created array is not getting freed. But I don't know, how to do this in the right way.

Can anyone help me with this? 
Thanks!

**EDIT**

I have done a several tests.
If i add the `DetachCurrentThread` function to the bottom of the second if(), the APP crashes, if `DetachCurrentThread` is getting called.

But i have added `DeleteLocalRef` in an other function, and the APP does not crash anymore.

So my question is: Do i have to call `DetachCurrentThread` in every function i call `AttachCurrentThread` or is it enough if i call that once to the end of the APP?

*Also updated the Code*

Comment: Where is `DetachCurrentThread` done?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#arrays

Comment: Is `DetachCurrentThread` needed, if i will call that function over and over again? I read in another Thread, that i have to do that just if i won't call the function again? Sorry, i am pretty new to Java using JNI ..

Comment: From the documentation: _"A native thread attached to the VM must call `DetachCurrentThread()` to detach itself before exiting"_. So you need to do it at some point before the native thread exits.

Comment: Regarding the thread attach/detach lifecycle: you should not attach the same thread again, unless you have detached it. You may put attach/detach around each call to your `jniBluetoothSend` function, but this may have quite significant overhead. Use Thread Local Storage to keep track of that. Also, don't waste time getting method IDs again and again: these IDs are constants, so you can reuse them in subsequent calls, even from different threads. You can keep it in **`pAdapter->pClasses`**. Also, make sure that **`pAdapter->pClasses->hgs_bluetooth`** is a Global Reference, calculated only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Everytime `ReleaseByteArrayElements()` gets called a warning shows up in Android Log from dalvik:
>
> JNI: unpinPrimitiveArray(0x428e84a8) failed to find entry (valid=1)

`ReleaseByteArrayElements` is meant to be paired with a previous call to `GetByteArrayElements`. From [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html):

> **Release<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements Routines**
>   `void Release<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements(JNIEnv *env,
>   ArrayType array, NativeType *elems, jint mode);`
>
> A family of functions that informs the VM that the native code no longer needs access to elems. The `elems` argument is a pointer derived from `array` using the corresponding `Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements()` function.

Since you didn't call `GetByteArrayElements` you also shouldn't call `ReleaseByteArrayElements`.

Note that `SetByteArrayRegion()` function is not one of the functions that pin an array, therefore it does not require a release.